# The place for the first record is empty in RDLC report

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reporting, rdlc

I have made a 2-column report that is like this :

```
Name1----------------------------Name3
Address1-------------------------Address3

Name2----------------------------Name4
Address2-------------------------Address4
```

But suddenly it started to give reports like this :

```
      ----------------------------Name3
       -------------------------Address3

Name1----------------------------Name4
Address1-------------------------Address4

Name2
Address2
```

Here is my code :

```
 public ActionResult Report()
        {
            LocalReport lr = new LocalReport();
            string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Report"), "Person.rdlc");
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
            {
                lr.ReportPath = path;
            }
            else
            {
                return View("Index");
            }
            List<Person> cm = new List<Person>();

            var viewModel = new PersonIndexData();

            viewModel.People = db.Person
            .Include(k => k.Groups)
            .OrderBy(k => k.Name);

            cm = viewModel.People.ToList();



            ReportDataSource rd = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", cm);
            lr.DataSources.Add(rd);
            string reportType = "pdf";
            string mimeType = string.Empty;
            string encoding = string.Empty;
            string fileNameExtension = string.Empty;



            string deviceInfo =

            "<DeviceInfo>" +
            "  <OutputFormat>pdf</OutputFormat>" +
            "  <PageWidth>8.5in</PageWidth>" +
            "  <PageHeight>12in</PageHeight>" +
            "  <MarginTop>0.5in</MarginTop>" +
            "  <MarginLeft>0.5in</MarginLeft>" +
            "  <MarginRight>1in</MarginRight>" +
            "  <MarginBottom>0.2in</MarginBottom>" +
            "</DeviceInfo>";

            Warning[] warnings;
            string[] streams;
            byte[] renderedBytes;

            renderedBytes = lr.Render(
                "pdf",
                deviceInfo,
                out mimeType,
                out encoding,
                out fileNameExtension,
                out streams,
                out warnings);


            return File(renderedBytes, mimeType);
        }
```

Namely the place for the first record is empty. Why do you think it happened and how I can get rid of it? I changed column spacing and margins but it didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: show the code producing this. you obviously have something wrong in an offset somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot fetch the first column value from a table.  That's the reason it cannot display the first column value.

Comment: If you have additional information that builds on your answer, please post it as an EDIT to your current answer rather than as a completely new answer. Currently, things look messy and two of your "answers" are barely more than comments.